# JQuery unbind events for objects in variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code for example:

```js
const $popup = $('#popup');
const $form = $(`<div>
                    <input type="text" value="Joe">
                    <button>save</button> 
                  </div>`);

$form.find('button').on('click', function() {
  $popup.empty();
});

$('#edit').on('click', function() {
  $popup.html($form);
});

// for simplicity
// $popup.html($form).empty().html($form); // events don't work
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<br><br>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

The problem is that after calling `html()` (as well as `remove()` and others) jquery removes events, although the object itself is still stored in a variable. Therefore, after the second call, you cannot press "save".

How do I force jquery not to delete events?

I considered the option with `clone()`, but then I can't save the text in input.

I considered the option with `detach()`, but I really have no control over what the popup does. I only have `show(html)` and `hide()` methods.

I considered the option with `$(document).on('click', 'some', function()`, so far this is the only working option, but not the most convenient

Comment: Your code looks fine - you just need to use `event delegation` for dynamically created elements like this => `$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {$popup.empty();});` so that **save** button works each time you append a `$form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also should use `.detatch` instead of `.empty`, so as to preserve the form elements when it's removed, because `.empty` [does](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.

```js
const $popup = $('#popup');
const $form = $(`<div>
                    <input type="text" value="Joe">
                    <button>save</button> 
                  </div>`);

$form.find('button').on('click', function() {
  $form.detach();
});

$('#edit').on('click', function() {
  $popup.html($form);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<br><br>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

Comment: .html is NOT similar to using element.innerHTML = newHTML. 
`html()` is similar `.empty().apend(el)`

Comment: Why do you say that? They do very similar things - `.html`, when called on a jQuery collection, sets the inner HTML of the elements in the collection. `.innerHTML`, when used on an element, sets the inner HTML of that element. `.append` does something entirely different - `.append` in jQuery (when passed in a jQuery collection or element) is like JS's `appendChild`, it takes the node(s) and inserts them into the DOM *without any serialization and deserialization*.

Comment: See source https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js
Method

```js
html: function( value ) {
/// ...
if ( elem ) {
  this.empty().append( value );
}
```

Comment: In old version more readable http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js see `html: function`

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. Nice catch, jQuery's docs on it didn't say it did anything other than set the HTML markup. I was misled. So the problem is only in the `.empty`.

Comment: I see you changed it to "detach()", but in my case, the popup does exactly "empty ()"

Comment: The `.empty` is the problem - that will remove all event handlers (that were attached via jQuery, at least). You should change the popup's code to use `.detach` instead of `.empty`, otherwise the problem you're currently seeing will be exhibited - the event handler(s) will be lost.

Comment: "detach" would be great.
but the problem is I have no control over what the popup is doing

Comment: The `$popup.empty();` will remove any event handlers from popup children. Do you have sufficient control that you can you add another click listener to the button at that point? Or you can use event delegation

Comment: yes, of course, I did not think about it. Thank you!
As a result, I had to do "detach()" first, and then call the popup methods.

In my example, need to do this
```js 
$form.detach ();
$popup.empty ();
```

In the real project, I had to do a lot of events for the popup